# signing of symbian app,is there any way now?

Tags: symbian, symbian3

Since nokia doesn't sign symbian apps any more,is there any alternative to sign app for symbian?

may be some behind the scene hack or bypass?

Comment: Did you find a way to sign your .sis files? symbiansigned.com and cer.opda.cn are super dead, no idea what to do. Self-signing is not enough for me, need some dev certificate

Answer (score 2):

symbiansigned.com and cer.opda.cn are dead, don't even mind getting developer certificates - just hack your phone, no way to do this otherwise nowadays:

https://shahbazalam781.blogspot.com/2013/04/hack-all-symbian-phones-s60v3-s60v5-s3.html

This works great, just try setting your phone Date & Time to somewhere about 2010-2012 when installing apps until it clicks. After hacking phone you won't need to do this anymore.

In case link dies:

> SIMPLEST PROCEDURE: First Download  3 Files
>
> ```
> DOWNLOAD-Norton-Symbian-Hack http://gallery.mobile9.com/f/3177996/
> DOWNLOAD-Rom-Patcher-Plus-v31 http://gallery.mobile9.com/f/3178010/
> DOWNLOAD-Xplore V1.58 http://gallery.mobile9.com/f/3175430/
> ```
>
> 1. Install “NortonSymbianHack.sisx”.
> 2. Launch it.
> 3. Go Options – Anti-Virus – Quarantine list.
> 4. Go Options – Restore. Accept prompt.
> 5. Exit application. Delete Norton from Application Manager (Symantec Symbian Hack). Also delete “C:\shared\” folder.
> 6. Install “RomPatcherPlus_3.1.sisx”.
> 7. Launch and apply patches:
>
>    - Open4all for full access to file system.
>    - Installserver for installing any unsigned applications.
>
> (If “Installserver” has red cross, follow steps 8 to 15.) (If checked,
>   reboot now your phone.)
>
> Note: Set patches to auto if needed. (Options – Add to auto)
>
> 8. Install X-Plore.
> 9. Open it.
> 10. Press (Menu – Tools – Configuration).
> 11. Check all (Show Hidden Files, etc.).
> 12. Open “installservers_pack.zip”.
> 13. Choose what Symbian OS you have. (List below)
> 14. Copy “installserver.exe” from the folder of your OS to “C:/sys/bin”. (No need to apply patch on RomPatcher.)
> 15. Reboot phone. Phone is now hacked.

Comment: Just a question about that. Since I seem to be able to install ROM Patcher and X-Plore without hacking my 6210 Navigator, what does this actually do? Do you know? (Though, I can't use an X-Plore installer "for hacked phones", so I don't really get what the hack does)

Comment: @DADi590 blog link is already dead, I'm glad I made a copy :) RomPatcher modifies your system files, so 1) you can write to C:/sys/bin and 2) run installserver (lets you bypass certificate checking while installing apps). X-Plore is just simple file explorer app. Yes, you can install them both without hacking, they don't do anything "illegal" themselves, patches inside quarantine are actual hacks.

Comment: Ah right, thank you for the explanation! Though, for some reason if I put installserver.exe where it's supposed, it doesn't work and the phone stops being able to install various programs. So I just don't use it at all and just use Install Server on ROMPatcher and it works perfectly. No idea what that file is for, but I can't use it (and it still works without using it haha).

Comment: @DADi590 The steps 8-15 were only if Rom Patcher step doesn't work. Otherwise, it works good overall

Answer (score 0):

Officially, you could of course continue using the developer certificates you might have, and if they are expired, the device time might be needed to be adjusted for the installation time.

Then also the self-signing works just as it used to. For any new certificates or signings, unfortunately there are no official help available.

Comment: the developer certificate i have is or limited imei,how can i sign it for all?as nokia used to sign it with their master certificate.

i know its possible,because some companies are doing it,but i have o idea how!

Comment: AFAIK there is no official way on getting the thing done in a way you would want it done. The developer certificate is limited to IMEIs, and there is no right way on going throuhg that limitation really.

Comment: I can 100% assure you people are doing it,there lies my problem,how on earth they are doing it !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app to sign Symbian apps.
The signing process is fail-able but the self-signing works perfectly.
Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RYWgU5mB4xrb_-IHwi0aw8zJucDbJ2ye)